# Case insensitive

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, case-insensitive

```
If TextBox2.Text = "a" AndAlso TextBox21.Text = "a" Then
        'MessageBox.Show("A")
        totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
    ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "b" AndAlso TextBox21.Text = "b" Then
        'MessageBox.Show("B")
        totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
    ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "c" AndAlso TextBox21.Text = "c" Then
        'MessageBox.Show("C")
        totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
    ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "d" AndAlso TextBox21.Text = "d" Then
        'MessageBox.Show("D")
        totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
    Else
        totWrong = totWrong + wrgAns
        Label13.Visible = True
    End If
```

I am trying to make the letters a,b,c,d that the user enters insensitive. Tried to use the UCase, but it did not work (not sure if I am using it wrong). I am in Visual Studio 2012 and using VB. Any references would be great.

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method : `String.Compare (String strA, String strB, Boolean ignoreCase)`

Pass `ignoreCase` argument with `true` will perform case insensitive comparison.

```
If String.Compare(TextBox2.Text, "a", true) = 0 AndAlso String.Compare(TextBox21.Text, "a", true) = 0 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("A")
        totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
    ElseIf String.Compare(TextBox2.Text, "b", true) = 0 AndAlso String.Compare(TextBox21.Text, "b", true) = 0 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("B")
        totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
    ElseIf String.Compare(TextBox2.Text, "c", true) = 0 AndAlso String.Compare(TextBox21.Text, "c", true) = 0 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("C")
        totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
    ElseIf String.Compare(TextBox2.Text, "d", true) = 0 AndAlso String.Compare(TextBox21.Text, "d", true) = 0 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("D")
        totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
    Else
        totWrong = totWrong + wrgAns
        Label13.Visible = True
    End If
```

Another idea is to uppercase or lowercase the input using [ToUpper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed.aspx) or [ToLower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at.aspx).

```
If TextBox2.Text.ToUpper() = "A" AndAlso TextBox21.Text.ToUpper() = "A" Then
            'MessageBox.Show("A")
            totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text.ToUpper() = "B" AndAlso TextBox21.Text.ToUpper() = "B" Then
            'MessageBox.Show("B")
            totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text.ToUpper() = "C" AndAlso TextBox21.Text.ToUpper() = "C" Then
            'MessageBox.Show("C")
            totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
        ElseIf TextBox2.Text.ToUpper() = "D" AndAlso TextBox21.Text.ToUpper() = "D" Then
            'MessageBox.Show("D")
            totCorrect = totCorrect + corAns
        Else
            totWrong = totWrong + wrgAns
            Label13.Visible = True
        End If
```

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN in VB.NET, you can use the [`Option Compare Statement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f.aspx) by simply adding 1 line of code to your file:

```vb
Option Compare Text
```

If you add the above line to the beginning of your code you are telling the CLR to switch from default (`Option Compare Binary`) to the case-insensitive comparison as the new default for the `=` operator.

I don't know if there is any C# alternative.