# Search a case sensitive string that takes from text box when using IF statement

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with some data, I want to "Do some thing" **if** the string (for example, Jon) in text box is Jon or JON or jon or ... My code:

```
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
          If dr.Cells(1).Value = TextBox1.Text Then
            'Do some thing
        End If
Next
```

Comment: `If dr.Cells(1).Value.ToString.ToUpper = TextBox1.Text.ToUpper Then...`

Comment: @Plutonix See [the Turkish Issue](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question to this was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606701/case-insensitive).

You can use the `String.Compare` method:

```
String.Compare(String strA, String strB, Boolean ignoreCase)
```

Pass true for the `ignoreCase` argument to perform a case-insensitive comparison.

```
If String.Compare(TextBox1.Text, "a", true) = 0 then
   ' Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use UCASE:

```
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If UCASE(dr.Cells(1).Value) = UCase(TextBox1.Text) Then
        'Do some thing
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The `String.ToUpper` should be preferred over the old VB6-style `UCase` function.  However, this solution won't work in all situations (Such as the infamous [Turkish Issue](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html)).

Comment: Good point. Thanks for sharing the Turkish Issue link as well, never heard of it until now.

ToUpper information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the overload to the `String.Equals` method, like this:

```
dr.Cells(1).Value.Equals(TextBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

There are other options too, such as using the Invariant Culture.  Which one you need will depend on your particular situation.